# Is there a way for plotting boundaries of Iran provinces in R?

Tags: r, gis, ggmap, r-sf

Is there a way to import data regarding province boundaries?
I understand that finding longitudes and latitudes for the capital (Tehran) is fairly easy, however, borders of a province are out of my league.
Something like this interactive map is simple and informative.
https://simplemaps.com/country/ir

Answer (score 2):

I've gone to [this site](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/administrative-boundaries-1-2) and downloaded the file called "irn_adm_unhcr_20190514_SHP.zip".

After you save and unzip it somewhere on your computer, run the following code to produce the below map:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

iran <- st_read("irn_admbnda_adm1_unhcr_20190514.shp")

ggplot(iran) + geom_sf()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to just select and plot a province. For example Qom province? How to work with this graph? I want to add some points to this map? For example  (x=50,y=35)? How to do it?

Comment: @Masoud It would be best to ask this as a separate question. https://gis.stackexchange.com/ is also a better place to ask this, as people there do this sort of stuff routinely.

Comment: How to set color to provinces? could you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69970229/custom-color-for-provinces-in-specific-country-using-raster-package-in-r ?

Answer (score 0):

Also, in general, searching for "[geographic entity] geojson" usually returns something useful.

https://github.com/mohsentaleb/iran-administrative-boundaries/blob/master/provinces.geojson